# The name 'Roles' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations, simplemembership

I have ported `Migrations` from a web app to a class library project.
Everything works fine, except that I can't call the `static class Roles`.

I have included the namespace `using System.Web.Security;` which is where the `Roles` are located.

Here is the Configuration.cs file contents:

```
namespace _DataContext.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using WebMatrix.WebData;
    using System.Web.Security;

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<_DataContext.DataContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(_DataContext.DataContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //

        SeedMembership();
    }

    private void SeedMembership()
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

        // doesn't work either:
        //var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
        //var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;

        if (Roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
          Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");
    }
  }
}
```

Error message is:

```
The name 'Roles' does not exist in the current context
```

What am I missing here?

**[Edit]**

I have been doing some more research and it appears that i have to create an object from `SimpleRoleProvider` in order to access the `RoleExists` method.

But why do i have to do it this way? Why can't i just use:

```
if (Roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))              
   Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");
```

`Roles` comes from a `static class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access *Roles* directly, but I would not recommend it when using the *SimpleMembership* providers. That being said, do you have the assembly *System.Web* referenced in your project?

The preferred method for getting the role provider is to do something like this:

```
  var roles = (WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;

  if (!roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
  {
      roles.CreateRole("Admin");
  }
```

If you compare the definition of *Roles* versus *SimpleRoleProvider* you will see there is quite a bit of difference.  It looks like the *SimpleRoleProvider* does not implement the complete interface for *Roles*, which is not required when implementing a custom provider. You may get a "not implemented" exception on some the methods if you call them directly from Roles.  *SimpleRoleProvider* also provides additional methods/properties that can be useful when using *SimpleMembership*.

Comment: Hi, thats it! i didn't had System.Web referenced! I've quickly compared SimpleRoleProvider with Roles. It seems that Roles provides more methods/properties than SimpleRoleProvider does. Also, why is that the preferred way? Why not directly in the if-statement checking if a role exists?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer SimpleRoleProvider is a "custom" role provider that does not have all of the methods implemented, because they are not needed. So by using SimpleRoleProvider instead of Role you will actually see only the methods implemented. If you call a non-implemented method from Role it will just throw an exception. Also SimpleRoleProvider provides additional methods not found in Role that are specific to using SimpleMembership.

Comment: So which one should i be using? the simple one or the role?

Answer (score 3):

Have you added the `roleManager` element to the `system.web` section of your `Web.config` file?   From [the MSDN page on Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx):

> To enable role management for your ASP.NET application, use the roleManager element of the system.web section in the Web.config file for your application, as shown in the following example.

The section looks like this:

```
  <roleManager defaultProvider="SqlProvider" 
    enabled="true"
    cacheRolesInCookie="true"
    cookieName=".ASPROLES"
    cookieTimeout="30"
    cookiePath="/"
    cookieRequireSSL="false"
    cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
    cookieProtection="All" >
    <providers>
      <add
        name="SqlProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
        connectionStringName="SqlServices"
        applicationName="SampleApplication" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Comment: Hi, i have the rolemanager and membership profider included in the app.config. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using seeding method in Class Library project.

You have to add two references

```
1. System.Web
2. System.Web.ApplicationServices
```

then resolve Roles, Membership from these references.